# how to do full text search on mongodb array fields?

Tags: java, mongodb, search, full-text-indexing

Hi my Mongo db fields as follows:

```
        "_id" : ObjectId("51d582be7a8d51bd29ca78a3"),
        "Filename" : "sample.pdfe",
        "Title" : null,
        "Author" : null,
        "ContentType" : "application/x-msdownload; format=pe32",
        "url" : "Z:sample.pdf",
        "Keywords" : ["php","java",".net","python"]
```

below is my code to do full text search on indexed fields

```
m = new Mongo("10.0.0.26", 27017);
DB db = m.getDB("soft") ;
DBCollection col = db.getCollection("metadatanew") ;
String collection = col.toString();
DBObject searchCmd = new BasicDBObject();
searchCmd.put("text", collection); 
searchCmd.put("search", name); 

CommandResult commandResult = db.command(searchCmd);

BasicDBList results = (BasicDBList)commandResult.get("results");

for (Iterator <Object> it = results.iterator();it.hasNext();)
{
    BasicDBObject result  = (BasicDBObject) it.next();
    BasicDBObject dbo = (BasicDBObject) result.get("obj");
    System.out.println(dbo.getString("Filename"));
}
```

I have used below command to create Text index on two fields:

```
db.metadatanew.ensureIndex({'Filename':"text"}, {'Keywords':"text"})
```

I have created text index on filename and keywords but i can able to do full text search on filename only, is there any wrong in my code, please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter on `ensureIndex` function is options. You should create an unique index on both fields:

```
db.metadatanew.ensureIndex( { "Keywords" : "text", "Filename" : "text"} )
```

See more:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/

Answer (score 2):

Another way to create an unique index on both fields :

```
BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
basicDBObject.append("Keywords", "text");
basicDBObject.append("Filename", "text");
dbCollection.createIndex(basicDBObject);
```